# c# polymorphism derive class to other derive class

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I have a class for example Tile, with derive classes TileA, TileB... TileF.

Now I want always that class TileF changes with a call into TileE.
And also TileE to TileD, and you can see the patern.
Can I specify it directly in TileF where it changes into.

I'm looking at `Activator.CreateInstance()`, but this gives me a object class, and not the wanted derive class.

How can I solve this?

I do this in my Main loop, where I specified that `Tile tile = TileF;`
then i want to do something like: `tile.change()` and that it changes in a `new TileE`

Some kind of code:

```
Class Tile{
   public abstract int Number{ get; }
}
Class TileF : Tile{
public override int Number
        {
            get
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
} 
Class TileE : Tile{
public override int Number
        {
            get
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }
} 

Class Main{
Tile tile = new TileF;
//change tile to TileE
tile = tile.ToNextTileType();

}
```

Comment: plz explain what is "TileF changes with a call into TileE". what are u trying to achieve. perhaps sharing some code will put us in better condition to answer

Comment: If the tiles all have the same behaviour, then inheritance is not the right tool for this job. Are there differences in behaviour between, for example, the `TileA` class and the `TileB` class?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear from your question what you want to do.  Are you familiar with 'is' and 'as' because that might help you along the way.

Comment: I can see `TileF` changing to `TileE` but not `TileE` to `TileB` - what logic is there at work here. Surely `TileE` should change to `TileD`?

Comment: I added some clarrification code. @ElRonnoco, the ... stands for that TileE -> TileD -> TileC -> TileB, but was a bit lazy to type that.

Comment: Best I can make of it is that you should not (try to) change tiles at all. Tiles don't change but a player moves to another tile instance. Make sure you understand references.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am looking at problem that involves changing the propertys and some virtual and abstract methods. Some propertys are constants for a class (like Number = 1 for ClassF and Number = 2 for ClassE), but others are the same like Position and such.

Comment: You should think about "what makes 2 tiles the same" and choose a solution that fits the OO possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an error in designing TileF/TileE etc. It was good enough to make a TileN, with a property that is replacing the inner working of a tile. This way I don't have to substitute a class, and thus avoiding this problem.

Answer (score 2):

When `TileE` and `TileF` are siblings, ie when they derive from a common baseclass, you **cannot** convert them directly.

There are several possible solutions but you don't provide much detail.

I think that maybe you should not use inheritance. Could a simple `enum TileType` solve your problem(s)?

Comment: Let's say that an other class like main holds a Tile tile = new TileF(), could I change that To TileE with a property of something of that in TileF?

Comment: @P-Storm: no the types are 'unrelated'.

Comment: @P-Storm - why? What are you trying to do that for?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have made a list of tile, and sometimes it happens that when a player leaves a tile, that the image and other property changes. TileF holds an other imageindex than TileE

Comment: @P-Storm - is it the case that the difference between each of the tile types is just that the properties of `Tile` just change values? Or are there other properties/methods that extend `Tile`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, a lot of propertys, but also some methods like `public override void Exit(){}`

Comment: @P-Storm - won't the properties be lost if you change types?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I'm searching for a structure that it wouldn't be lost. Currently I do that through a constructor, that accepting a Tile, where the propertys that may not be lost are being set. Other propertys are in the class, like the example with Number.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at interfaces. Interface lets unrelated objects be treated as the same thing when you reference a type of the Interface type e.g.

```
class ClassOne : ICommon;
class ClassTwo : ICommon;
class ClassThree : ICommon;

ClassOne x = new ClassOne();
ClassTwo y = new ClassTwo();
ClassThree z = new ClassThree();

List<ICommon> data = new List<ICommon>();
data.Add(x);
data.Add(y);
data.Add(z);

foreach(ICommon item in data)
{
    item.InterfaceMethodOne();
}
```

This might not be what you want but it is worth looking into.

James :-)

Comment: The "problem" with this code is, that I have to change the type, or better, the propertys, that are static with each class.

Comment: How do you mean change the properties? If you have a base-class or interface that is common to all the objects you can interrogate the object to determine it's true class.

Comment: I don't want to have a large list like "if class is this than change to other class." Take as example that z is changing into a ClassTwo, without the "if class is thing"

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the static and the dynamic type of an object. The static type of an object can be changed, that is you may write `BaseType base = (BaseType)new DerivedType();`. Changing the static type of an instance is called *casting*.

The compiler will restrict the call to methods, fields and properties present in the `BaseType` and all of its base types. The dynamic type of an object however may never change and in this case `base` still has the dynamic type `DerivedType`. The condition `if (base is DerivedType)` will return true in this case. You can only "change" the dynamic type by instantiating a new object of the target type and copy the desired values to the new instance. This process is called *mapping*.

Btw, `Activator.CreateInstance` will only give you an instance of the static type `object`, but likely with a different dynamic type. You can change the static type by casting it to a type that you know the object should have: `(DerivedType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DerivedType))`. You can also use the generic variant, then this cast is done within the method: `Activator.CreateInstance<DerivedType>()`. Semantically there is no difference, except that the generic variant is easier to read.

EDIT:

Does this solve your problem?

```
public abstract class Tile {
  public abstract int Number { get; }
  public abstract Tile Advance();
}

public class TileA : Tile {
  public override int Number { get { return 1; } }
  public override Tile Advance() { return new TileB(); }
}

public class TileB : Tile {
  public override int Number { get { return 2; } }
  public override Tile Advance() { return new TileC(); }
}

public class TileC : Tile { ... }
```

You can also define the "state machine" in the abstract class like so:

```
public abstract class Tile {
  public abstract int Number { get; }
  public sealed Tile Advance() {
    if (this is TileA) {
      return new TileB();
    else if (this is TileB) {
      return new TileC();
    }
  }
}
```

Another alternative is of course to model the state machine entirely in one object:

```
public enum TileState { TileA, TileB, TileC };
public class Tile {
  private TileState state = TileState.TileA; // initial state

  public int Number {
    get {
      switch (state) {
        case TileState.TileA: return 1;
        case TileState.TileB: return 2;
        ...
        default: return -1; // or throw exception
      }
    }
  }

  public void Advance() {
    switch (state) {
      case TileState.TileA: state = TileState.TileB; break;
      case TileState.TileB: state = TileState.TileC; break;
      ...
      default: // exception ?
    }
  }
}
```

In the last example, the behavior of your object changes depending on the state variable. It's not a new instance, but it can do something completely different. I hope something of this could help.

Comment: The problem here is that I cannot find a way to strong type the type. I can make a abstract property Type in the Tile class, but can't cast it to that property, like you said, it will be a type object. So for the clarrification

`Type t = typeof(TileE);
Tile tile = new TileF();
tile = (??t??)ctivator.CreateInstance(t)
//tile is a TileE`

Comment: I don't understand your code. If you know that t is a Type that represents TileE then you could do `Tile tile = Activator.CreateInstance<TileE>();` straight away. I edited my answer to hopefully give you some alternatives on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Did find that I could join the tiles thus avoiding the problem :)